# Vaadin: TextArea scrolling doesn't work

Tags: textarea, vaadin

I have something similar to this code:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setSizeFull();
Panel dataPanel = new Panel("Panel", textArea);
dataPanel.setSizeFull();
textArea.setValue(... some very long text...);
```

The problem is that this **TextArea** appears without vertical scrollbar (and mouse-wheel scrolling also doesn't work), although inner text is longer than TextArea height (I can navigate lower using cursor and keyboard down arrow).

How do I enable scrolling in this component?

Comment: Try change in css `.v-textarea {  overflow-y: auto ! important;}`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. You can suggest it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it CSS also like below .

```
.v-textarea { overflow-y: auto ! important;}
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit weird, but as per the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-textarea.html#components.textarea.wordwrap) if you disable word-wrapping in a text-area, you'll get the vertical scroll-bar:

> **Word Wrap**
>
> The setWordwrap() sets whether long lines are wrapped ( true - default) when the line length reaches the width of the writing area. **If the word wrap is disabled (false), a vertical scrollbar will appear instead**. The word wrap is only a visual feature and wrapping a long line does not insert line break characters in the field value; shortening a wrapped line will undo the wrapping.

The following code sample illustrates this behaviour with Vaadin 8.0.6. Please note my class extends `Panel` to match your sample but at this point you can eliminate it:

```java
public class PanelWithScrollableTextField extends Panel {
    public PanelWithScrollableTextField() {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWordWrap(false);
        textArea.setSizeFull();
        setContent(textArea);
        setSizeFull();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(value -> buffer.append(value).append("\r\n"));
        textArea.setValue(buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: text-area-scrolling]

---

**P.S.** I know it's a bit weird to grasp, but panels are used to [scroll *surfaces* that are larger then the panel size](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-panel.html#layout.panel.scrolling), so if we'd get it working, you'd be scrolling the text area itself, not its content. You can see below a sample to better understand what I mean:

```java
public class PanelWithScrollableTextField extends Panel {
    public PanelWithScrollableTextField() {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWordWrap(false);
        textArea.setHeight("500px"); // fixed size with height larger than the panel
        setContent(textArea);
        setHeight("100px"); // fixed height smaller than the content so we get a scroll bar

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(value -> buffer.append(value).append("\r\n"));
        textArea.setValue(buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: panel-scroll]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but I do need word-wrapping in my TextArea :(